# How can I add background image to Angular selector?

Tags: html, css, angular, background-image

I am trying to add background image to Angular selector, but its not working for me. Below is the code

```
    <app-highway-card [ngStyle]="{'background-image':'url(https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2021/09/04/09/32/road-6597404__340.jpg)'}" [highway]="highway"></app-highway-card>
```

Comment: Try `"{'background-image':'url(' + 'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2021/09/04/09/32/road-6597404__340.jpg' + ')'}"`

Comment: I tried, did not work. Unable to see the image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `display: 'block'` to the styles:

```
[ngStyle]="{'background-image':'url(https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2021/09/04/09/32/road-6597404__340.jpg)', display: 'block'}"
```

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-zmjsjo?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html